# Extracting animation keyframes in Baylon.js

Tags: javascript, babylonjs

I am teaching myself babylon.js and I am creating an Animations library class (in javascript). I wanted to know if babylon.js provides a tool that would enable me to extract the total animation keyframe for my zombie character?

What I am doing as a workaround is hard-typing the total frames but I wanted to do it dynamically.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have an array called mesh.skeleton.animations.

Each animation has a keys property containing all keyframes